# Cookie disabled issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies

While testing our site with IE, we were disabling/enabling the cookies from the privacy settings tab. But this not does seem to work as expected. (for the first time it worked, and from then on,it stopped working).Chrome and Firefox seem to work fine though.

the logic we have written to check if cookies are enabled/disabled is as follows:

We try to create a test cookie using document.cookie(we have not specified any domain nor an expiry date). If the cookie can be created, then we say the cookies are enabled,else they are disabled.We then go ahead and remove the test cookie. The problem in IE is that,even if the cookies are enabled,we are not able to create the test cookie/if they are disabled, we are able to create the test cookie. It happens both the ways.

any thoughts/ideas?

Comment: have you tried to play around with security settings? setting them to low to see if something changes etc.?

Comment: I have found that older versions of IE, after changing the security settings you have to start a new browser session to get it to function properly.  That means closing and restarting all of your open IE windows.

Comment: yeah we have tried with all the different security settings, but with no luck.

Comment: @marteljn we have restarted the browser multiple times. Still doesn't seem to work.We have tested with IE 8,9 and 10.