# Is it possible to block cookies in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I am testing(on localhost on Windows 7 64 Bit) the behaviour of my web application when cookies are blocked.

When testing on IE11, it seems you cannot block cookies, even when the IE11 settings show that I have blocked cookies.(I have also tried uninstalling & re-installing IE11, just in case something was broken, but cannot block cookies.)

I have researched and been to the following places but no answers;

1. [Cookies disable doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11 using advance setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769980/cookies-disable-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-11-using-advance-setting)
2. [Cookie disabled issue in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358244/cookie-disabled-issue-in-ie?rq=1)
3. [document.cookie is still accessible on IE11, even though cookies are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536141/document-cookie-is-still-accessible-on-ie11-even-though-cookies-are-disabled?rq=1)
4. https://superuser.com/questions/1000545/internet-explorer-11-cant-disable-localhost-cookies

Or may be I should just forget about Internet Explorer ?
(Thanking the coding community in advance)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the same issue with me. i searched a lot too.
What i figure out is that Cookies setting only impact on websites which contains real domain (ie: examples.com, abc.net,...)

1. you can change the localhost domain by editing a host file in (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc)
2. Include one line at the end of that text file like below:

127.0.0.1 testweb.net

Now, whenever you type testweb.net, it will return the page as same as the localhost does.